# Can’t Reset Stack from Tab button

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I don't know how to reset the stack with a custom tabbar component.

```
Tab 1(Stack)
  -ScreenA
  -ScreenB
Tab 2(Stack)
  -ScreenA2
  -ScreenB2
Tab 3
```

https://snack.expo.io/@tamsynjennifer/stack-inside-custom-tabs

Comment: Hope it would help you - https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1557#issuecomment-302110938

Comment: Thanks that does help but it only works for resetting one stack and route. I have multiple tabs with multiple stacks. Each Tab Icon when pressed navigates to a stack with <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => jumpTo(route.key)> but the NavigationActions only accept one routeName: '..'. Would I need to pass each stack individually?